# How can I download the Azure Bot source code in Python?

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

Via the link below I know it is possible to create a Web App Bot in Python and to deploy it. At the moment I have a created a bot remotely in Azure using QnA Maker, and I was hoping to download the source code in Python and build some feature locally and deploy it afterwards. I am currently stuck at this, because the download source code options only lets me download the source code in C#. In Configuration -> General settings -> Stack settings, I changed the Stack to Python already, but this seems to have no effect. Thus I have 2 questions:

1. How can I download the bot's source code in Python?
2. If the Stack setting did not change the source code, what is this setting's purpose?

Please let me know whether I need to change/add something to this question and/or problem statement. Thanks a lot!

link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/python/bot-builder-python-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Answer (score 0):

You can't download python source code off azure, because there are no templates on Azure for python. The only templates that exist are node and C#. When you clicked the 'Create a bot' on Azure, there is a setting in the creation blade that shows what language to create your bot in:

[image: Create a bot language choices]

I'm not sure how you're downloading your source code, as when I got to  my bots to get the code, there isn't an option to change my language, only a prompt asking if I want my app settings and keys.

[image: keys]

The bot framework samples repo has a sample QnA bot [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/python/11.qnamaker). You can add your qna keys into this bot, test locally and deploy from local up to azure. But there is no way to pull 'source code' in python from azure.